# Use lapply to deal with content of lists

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have to split for each data frame the content of the column `mod` when `|` is present. Find my code below. I want to use lapply but it does not work. Other suggestions are still fine

```
prot<-rep('AAAA', times=5)
mod<-c("[5] C(+57.02)", "[5] C(+57.02|[5] C(+57.02))", "[5] C(+57.02)", "[55] C(+57.02|[55] C(+57.02))", "f36")
FramA<-data.frame(prot, mod)
FramA["mod"] <- lapply(FramA["mod"], as.character)
outdm<-list(FramA, FramA)
somelistmod <- lapply(outdm, function(x) strsplit(outdm[[x]]$mod, split = "\\|"))
```

That's the error I get

```
Error in outdm[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
Called from: strsplit(outdm[[x]]$mod, split = "\\|")
Browse[1]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are using the anonymous function call, then we can extract the 'mod' column with `x$mod` or `x[["mod"]]`.  Here we are looping through the `list` 'outdm' which is a `list` of `data.frame`s.  The anonymous function `x` represents the data.frame object

```
lapply(outdm, function(x) strsplit(x$mod, split = "\\|"))
```